# Kotlin way to update elements in one list from elements in another list?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin noob here, I'm trying to update the element in `listFirst` by comparing some attribute (say, `topicId`) of the elements from the `listSecond`, both list contains the same type of element. I had the following code but it looks ugly to me. Is there anyway to make it look better or more efficient in Kotlin? Thank you! (The compiler version: java 8)

```
...
outputList = mutableListOf<MyObject>()
listFirst.forEach {
            element1 ->
            run {
                val t = listSecond.firstOrNull { element1.topicId == it.topicId }
                if (t != null) {
                    outputList.add(t)
                } else {
                    outputList.add(element1)
                }
            }
        }

return outputList
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do, because your current logic looks like it creates an enormous list that is the size of both lists multiplied by each other because for every element in the first list, it adds as many elements as the second list has.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sorry, my previous logic was wrong. I've updated the code. thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `run` enclosure in your code is not being used for anything so you might as well remove it. Anyway, you can use `map` and an elvis operator to reduce your code quite a bit:

```
return listFirst.map { element1 ->
        listSecond.firstOrNull { element1.topicId == it.topicId } ?: element1
    }
```

If these are long lists, it would be more efficient to create a Map out of the second list so you aren't having to iterate it repeatedly with `firstOrNull`. This would change it from *O(n^2)* to *O(n)*.

```
val mapSecond = listSecond.associateBy { it.topicId }
return listFirst.map { element1 ->
        mapSecond[element1.topicId] ?: element1
    }
```